# C# ExcelDataReader Error - 'Invalid file signature' for XLSB format

Tags: c#, .net, excel, asp.net-web-api, exceldatareader

I am receiving **'Invalid file signature'** error when I try to read xlsb file using below code.

If I use CreateReader, then I am receiving **'Detected ZIP file, but not a valid OpenXml file'** error. I have also tried other options as given below but nothing works for me.

Can somebody help me to read xlsb file.

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(srcContent);

public static DataSet GetXLSBData(Stream stream)
{
    DataSet dataSet;

    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream))
    {

        dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
    }

    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        table.TableName = table.TableName.Trim();
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

Other options tried:

```
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(stream)
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
```

Comment: Try converting it to xlsx format.

Comment: Please refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398259/13378146).

Comment: FYI, looks like the next version of ExcelDataReader will add support for XLSB, but it's not released yet, and their repo has been quiet for the last 6 months... :-/

Comment: Facing the exact same issue! I am looking for a library that could help opening a XLSB file in .Net Core 3 and nothing really works so far

Comment: Have you tried using [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)?

Answer (score -1):

My proposal

c# code :

```
 using (XlsxOrXlsbReadOrEdit excelFile = new XlsxOrXlsbReadOrEdit())
{
   excelFile.Open("file.xlsx");
   excelFile.ActualSheetName = "sheet1";
   object[] row = null;
   while (excelFile.Read())
   {
       if (row == null)
       {
           row = new object[excelFile.FieldCount];
       }
       excelFile.GetValues(row);
   }
}
```

**disclimer - I am creator of SpreadSheetTasks**
Links

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadSheetTasks/